# Getting Proper PDF Hyperrefs

Tags: table-of-contents

What is the easiest way of including your `listoffigures` and `listoftables` in your `tableofcontents` to have it display

> List of Figures ......... `page number`

in the table of contents?

I am using :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace*{6.35in}\underline{page}}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Figures}    
\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Tables}
\newpage 

\chapter{Intro} \lipsum[1]

\section{Learning the Art of Thinking} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what `part` is for, but it seems to put a space between the `LoF` and `LoT`, because when taken out, they are side-by-side. I want the `LoF` and `LoT` to be in the `TOC` and just be formatted normally as if chapter or subsection with the correct page number. With the above code, the word "Figures" overwrites the `\underline{page}` which is not wanted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way depends on the class you are using.

**1st Alternative:** If you are using a [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class, the easiest way would be to use class option `listof=totoc`:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\hspace*{\protect\fill}\protect\underline{page}%
    \protect\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

I've used `\hspace*{\fill}` to right align the `page`. I cannot recommend doing something else at the example above, but nevertheless you may use another length than `\fill`, if don't want it right aligned. The `\protect` commands are only to prevent, e.g. `\hspace` from breaking at the moving argument of `\addtocontents`.

**2nd Alternative:** With [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) you simply don't have to use the star version of the commands:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\hspace*{\protect\fill}\protect\underline{page}%
    \protect\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* % no entry to toc itself
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

**3rd Alternative:** With standard classes you may use package [tocbibind](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind).

**4th Alternative:** Another solution may be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\hspace*{\protect\fill}\protect\underline{page}%
    \protect\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage% make sure to be on the correct page with the following two commands
\csname phantomsection\endcsname% anchor for links usings hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\listfigurename}% entry at the toc
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage% make sure to be on the correct page with the following two commands
\csname phantomsection\endcsname% anchor for links usings hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\listtablename}% entry at the toc
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

List of figures and list of tables are topmost level headings, usually may by `\chapter*` at report and book classes and `\section*` at article classes. Because of this, the toc entries of both should be top level entries. That's the reason I'm using `chapter` for the second argument of `\addcontentsline` at the example above using `book` class (with `article` class you should change it into `section`). Top level entries at book, report or article does not have dots between title and page number. But this depends on the class. So if you're using another class, the result may be another.

**Addon to all those alternatives:** And if you like to have dots at chapter entries with either KOMA-Script classes or standard classes you may use a package, e.g. add

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
```

at the example with `scrbook` or `book` above.

Here an working example using `tocstyle` with `report` (because you've told, that you're using this class) and the code above:

```
\documentclass{report}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\hspace*{\protect\fill}\protect\underline{page}%
    \protect\par
  }%
}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage% make sure to be on the correct page with the following two commands
\csname phantomsection\endcsname% anchor for links usings hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\listfigurename}% entry at the toc
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage% make sure to be on the correct page with the following two commands
\csname phantomsection\endcsname% anchor for links usings hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\listtablename}% entry at the toc
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

with result:

[image: tocstyle does work with report]

And here the same using `tocstyle` and `tocbibind` and `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\hspace*{\protect\fill}\protect\underline{page}%
    \protect\par
  }%
}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

With result:

[image: toystyle and tocbibind and hyperref with report]

Comment: Thanks! Thats works. Three things. 1) How can one you adjust the horizontal spacing of where you would like the `\underline{page}`. 2) There are no `\ldots` after the `LoF` and `LoT`. 3) Also wold like if it can be flexible to do different things with the fonts of the `LoF` and `LoT` instead of being just one standard font and size. Oh, and one last thought, I also need one for an abstract page. How can you put that in `TOC` elegantly? It is right after `LoT`

Comment: @nightowl it may help to tell Schweinebacke what documentclass you're using.

Comment: @nightowl: I've already written at the first version of my answer: everything depends on the class you are using, e.g. using a KOMA-Script class you may use `\setkomafont{chapterentry}` to change the font of the chapter level entries. So please make a MWE and tell more about what you are doing. Nevertheless I've added some additional information to my answer.

Comment: @nightowl: I've already explained at the answer, how to modify the horizontal positioning of `\underline{page}`. Simply replace `\fill` by the length you want. There was an typo at the `tocstyle` lines. Using `allwithdot` instead of `allwithdots` works with `report` as well. Simply add the lines to the `scrbook` example and replace `scrbook` by `report` shows it. See package manual for more information about predefined styles and how to change settings. Even combination of `tocbibind` and `tocstyle` does work.

Comment: @nightowl: Sorry, but I cannot help you, if you don't tell me, what's the problem. Have you even tried my examples? What's the error message? I've added several examples to show, that `tocstyle` with standard class does not generally result in errors and even combination with `tocbibind` does work.

Comment: @nightowl: I've added some structural kind of headlines to show you more, what are the alternative suggestions and what is only an addon you've asked for and that may be combined with the alternative answers or may be omitted. Each of the examples has been tested and works!

Comment: @nightowl: If you really thought, that `\hspace*{\hspace{5cm}}` is correct syntax please read an introduction to LaTeX. `\hspace*{5cm}` or your previous `\hspace*{6.25}` would be correct syntax. This shouldn't be hard to understand …

Answer (score 4):

Use [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package, it works with `book`, `report` and `article` classes.
From it's manual:

> The tocbibind package enables the titles of the Table of Contents, 
>   the List of Figures, the List of Tables, the Bibliography and the
>   Index all to be added to the Table of Contents.  By default, all of
>   these document elements, if they exist, will be incorporated into the
>   Table of Contents (ToC for short).  Package options are available to
>   switch oﬀ any of these inclusions.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. That simple fix did the trick. Do you know if they have an option for putting dots like `\usetocstyle{allwithdots}` ?, as mentioned by `Schweinebacke`.

Comment: @nightowl: I've already told you yesterday, that you may use `tocbibind`. And you may combine both packages (see my comment below my answer).

Comment: @nightowl: I think `Schweinebacke` is right, in his first answer already mention `tocbibind` package plus some other options in case you don't use standard classes. I wrote this one because I didn't carefully read his message. It would be better to accept Schweinebacke answer.

Comment: @nightowl: I've suggested to use `tocbibind` independent of `tocstyle`. Adding `tocstyle` has been done only because of your additional question how to add dots to the entries.

Comment: @Ignasi: I haven't any problem with accepting your answer. Even the statement, that yours is better than mine, wouldn't be a problem. But, that a warning message of a package suggested to realize an additional question from a comment or unknown error messages, that are not a result of my tested examples, should disqualify my complete answer isn't very nice.

Comment: @Ignasi: Was there a way to add some option to get the dots just using the `tocbibind`package?

Comment: @nightowl: I've never used `tocbibind` but looking for `dots` and `\tableofcontents` here I've found [line of dots in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15800/line-of-dots-in-table-of-contents).

Answer (score 0):

After your `\listoftables` or `\listoffigures` command you can manually add a ToC reference with:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{sectiontype}{ToC Entry}
```

Depending on what depth your toc is set at, i.e. does it show chapters only, sections, subsection, etc... choose "sectiontype" to be one that is displayed appropriately for you.

"ToC Entry" is what you want displayed in your ToC.

So, for your tables you could use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the list is longer than one page.

Comment: I use this for a LOF that is ~3 pages @ 2 columns.

Comment: @Steve: In this case the last page of you LOF will be added to the toc instead of the first one …